# OP asked about problems after using X; the right answer is "use Y instead"; what should I do?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, xy-problem

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26699524/509868) the OP *probably* uses `freopen` when the better option would be `fopen` (or even its C++ counterpart). An answer suggested C++ code that would solve the OP's problem, and it seems good.

However, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26699681/509868) is (currently) just a piece of code. What should I do about it?

- Downvote? (I feel reluctant to do so because the OP said the solution was good)
- Wait until it gets through the low-quality answer queue? (I am not sure it's there)
- Add explanations? (I'd have to add much text, so the authorship of the answer would suffer)
- Request explanations from the answerer? (There are multiple points to explain - how to use `fopen` and whether one can use C++ - so I doubt the author can do it without causing more confusion)

There is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26699708/509868), which just tells that the question is duplicate. What should I do with it?

- Downvote? (because one should have pressed the <kbd>close</kbd> button instead of answering)
- Upvote? (because it answers the question)

Should I add my own answer, which is a mish-mash of the two existing answers, with my explanations?

Should I vote to close as duplicate?

Also, it's not readily apparent from the question that OP suffers from the X-Y problem (trying to use `freopen` and suffering, while the right tool to use is `fopen`). If the question is marked duplicate, will it hurt future viewers?

Comment: Well, the good old XY problem question, let's see if there's a canonical way, how to handle this here (My guts say: Answer the Y problem as best as you can, while pointing out why X is barking up the wrong tree at the same time).

Comment: Ah, the old [Old Shoe or Glass Bottle?](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925) problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first answer you link completely misses the point of the question. But it's an **attempt** to answer, and does not violate any site rules. So I don't think there's a reason for it to be deleted. Downvoting would seem appropriate to me. And if you want to add a comment to explain why you believe it's not a good answer, you're free to do that. I don't think trying to edit it would be productive, it's not even close to giving a useful solution to the question.

The second answer you link is borderline link-only. It does say that there is no portable way to solve the problem, so it does provide *some* information beyond just giving a link. Certainly not a high quality answer either. The information at the link is actually addressing the question directly, but it should be summarized in the answer. I certainly wouldn't upvote it for this reason, but voting is your personal choice.

If you find an on-site duplicate, certainly vote to close as duplicate. Note that the link in one of the answers is to an off-site resource, so it's not suggesting that the question is a duplicate.

Based on the comments, the OP probably does not fully understand their own question, and is going down the wrong path in solving their personal problem at hand. So in that sense, it could be an XY problem. But the question as it stands looks clear to me, and could be answered. So unless there is a duplicate on SO, I think it would be fine to leave it open.

Comment: I haven't looked at the answer yet but `it's not even close to giving a useful solution to the question.` would be a sufficient reason to vote to delete for me.

Comment: @MartinSmith Check it out. The way I understand the site guidelines, answers that make an attempt to answer the question do not qualify for deletion as NAA. And I think that's the case here.

Comment: They don't qualify for "flagging" as NAA. But if they don't contribute anything useful and are worsening the signal to noise ratio I'd still vote to delete them. (20K+ users can vote to delete, needs 3 votes for the deletion to happen)

Comment: If I see plain code with no explanation in my code review queue, I will ask for the author to explain how or why it works, if possible. Salvaging a code block with explanation is far more practical than deleting it outright, I think, especially if it were to actually work.

Answer (score 4):

The OP's question about freopen() is unclear. They didn't write what they want to accomplish. The answer assumes they want to use stdout again after redirecting it to a file.

Answering the question in its current form encourages writing non-portable code and bad practice of redirecting stdout in the code. There is a reason why consoles have redirection characters (<, >, >>, |) -- it is to give user more choice over what to do with the program input and output.

Comment: So what should I do? "Unclear question" - vote to close as "unclear"? "Answering encourages bad practice" - downvote the answers?

Comment: Personally, I would vote to delete the question since nothing good can be learned from it or the answers provided.