# How to deal with XY problem that ends up with an accepted answer that is a bad practice?

Tags: discussion

I've looked at some of the information on meta about XY problems and dealing with them.  Just now I was on some comment threads regarding the question here [Create factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29167964/create-factory-pattern?noredirect=1#comment46555494_29167964).

Ultimately an answer that solved the X part of the question was accepted, but it is clear from the OPs comments that they don't understand the meaning of the answer. The accepted answer would also be confusing for people trying to understand the Factory pattern.

I ended up down voting the question, but is there any other means of moderation available to keep incorrect information from bubbling up from a query?

Note that I am not criticizing the person that received credit for the answer as based on the straight reading of the question their response will solve the problem.  But as an example of using a factory pattern it is incorrect.

For the possible duplicate [Overriding Accepted Answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252015/overriding-accepted-answers) I don't really want to override the accepted answer, just want to indicate that this answer doesn't reflect a good example of a factory pattern.

Comment: Why downvote the question? The OP asked an answerable question, and there is an accurate answer even with the most votes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29168061/1026459 . Just downvote the answer if you feel it is bad practice.

Comment: It represents 0.00013% of the C# questions.  Google is unlikely to put it at the top.  In fact, none of the C# posts at SO about the factory pattern is on top, a possible side effect of SO having a lot of bad ones :)  So this isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: @Travis It's not the answer that I have an issue with because it solves the question posted.  My issue is with the entire post being referred to as a Factory pattern when both the question and the answer would be a bad example of the problem.

Comment: The question was only asked 3 hours ago? This might be a problem for [an "entrenched" answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287692/1858225), but it's hard to know exactly how things will shake out for a newish question.

Comment: If I had 250 more rep, I'd vote to reopen.

Comment: see also: [OP asked about problems after using X; the right answer is “use Y instead”; what should I do?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275913/op-asked-about-problems-after-using-x-the-right-answer-is-use-y-instead-what)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you can do is downvote.

The question doesn't qualify for any of the close reasons (note: I did not try to find any dupes).  It's a clear question with an MCVE and asks a very specific question that describes what he wants to happen vs. what he is getting.  That alone puts in head and shoulders above some of the other crap we get here.

As far as it being "incorrect", that's your opinion and you can express that with a downvote.  I wholly agree that the example given is not how a factory pattern is intended to be used.  **BUT** I can't dictate to every developer in the world that what I believe to be correct is the only correct way of doing something and thou shalt be damned for doing it any other way!  And even if I could, I can't enforce it.

[image: Failed to read]

People will do dumb things.  Sometimes they have to learn from their own mistakes.  The best you can do is warn them off with a downvote and maybe a comment and hope they heed the warning.  If a few "DANGER" and "WARNING" signs could prevent all the dumb real world things people do, that would be fantastic.  But it doesn't work that way.  So the best we can do is post the warning signs and hope.

Comment: I'll add a comment to the accepted answer and move on.

Comment: Dumb bear. Can't you read?

Comment: Downvoting is **not** all you can or even *should* do; this is one of the best uses for *comments*. Comment on the accepted answer so that future readers have a chance to be able to see the problems with it, and comment on the question asking the OP to select a more appropriate answer. Downvotes do not, on their own, provide nearly enough information to OP or to future site visitors.

Comment: @KyleStrand Hence the idea to comment in the last paragraph.

Comment: @Becuzz No offense, but putting the phrase "and maybe a comment" in the middle of your last paragraph is not enough to offset starting your answer with "all you can do is downvote."

Comment: @KyleStrand you're so meta :-)