# How to behave when OP claims that someone misunderstood his question, but in fact the answer is right to the point?

Tags: discussion, answers, behavior

15+ hours ago I answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337693/wpf-splashscreen-with-system-threading-thread/52337752#52337752).

OP then [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337693/wpf-splashscreen-with-system-threading-thread/52337752#comment91623167_52337752) that he wants to use BackgroundWorker instead. I gently said that this is another whole question and it wasn't asked in the original post. A few hours later, OP leaves a comment asking me to answer [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341692/vb-net-and-wpf-splashscreen-with-system-threading-thread). I know this is not encouraged, and maybe I should have flagged the comment and moved on. Since I had time, I took a look at the other question which has a problem that I have faced before and had the solution.

Note that the second question has another OP but I feel he's the same with two accounts or so.

After answering the question, OP also said that he's having other troubles. Specifically that the second window is taking 5 seconds long to show and it's not hiding. Generously, I gave him the *best* solution that *I could* find since I am not that expert in `WPF`. After a small [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180099/discussion-between-paul-karam-and-danny-coleiro) with the OP, he decided to remove the comments he initially posted and told me that I didn't understand his question and that I am misleading other users who might be reading his post. He added a new comment stating:

> You are trying to change my original question. I have posted two example codes which are not using Loaded event. So, please answer this question without using Load event.

I thought that I did miss something actually, and re-read his question multiple time. After making sure that my initial answer did solve the main and only issue the OP talked about. I edited my answer and left the OP a message that my answer does, actually, solve his main problem and that he (again maybe?) needs another post or to reformat his question. I also removed the part where I tried to help him with the desired behavior that he didn't mention in the first place.

My edit was this:

> According to your comment: You are trying to change my original question. I have posted two example codes which are not using Loaded event. So, please answer this question without using Load event.
>
> I have already answered the STA problem you had. Any other problem requires a whole new question. Or by simple reformating of your current question to include the whole intended behavior.

Surprisingly enough, after this happened, he deleted his comment and posted:

> Paul Karam Please delete your whole answer in order to keep my question understandable to other people.

I am sure that I didn't misunderstand his original question and that my answer fixes it. If I missed anything, please shed the light on it.

I would like to ask what should I do now, or what should have happened in first place. Should I have flagged the comment at the start asking for an answer to the other question? Should I currently flag the question for moderator attention, since it *seems* legit and there's no other option as off-topic or unclear? Or should I just leave it as it is and move on since I've done my part?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288422/how-to-deal-with-xy-problem-that-ends-up-with-an-accepted-answer-that-is-a-bad-p

Comment: Perhaps applicable: [What is a help vampire?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258206)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, I did actually remember that post when this happened.

Comment: Please don't use your answer to add meta-commentary about your answer, however. I removed that part from your post, and left a comment for the OP to not make demands.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you, my bad. I didn't intend to keep it there but must be the habit of "I'll do that later".

Comment: For what to do: flag the comment, either as 'no longer needed' or with a custom flag to alert moderators of the behaviour. Your answers are there not just for the OP but also for *future visitors with the same problem*. If you write your answer as clearly as possible to that audience, then your work is basically done. If the OP now has a solution, that's great, but you can only lead a horse to water, not make them drink.

Comment: answer him using the lebanese way ;)

Comment: @PeterHaddad I am sure this would have broken the code of conduct in all possible ways. No sorry :P

Comment: @PaulKaram yes I know, I'm joking :p First time I see an active person from Lebanon here lol

Comment: It happened to me when I asked a question with a bounty [How to achieve vector swizzling in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51641131/8524922) and the top answer totally doesn't answer my question but after a lot of work, I've come to a solution (not the perfect one but it does answer my question and on-the-point) and posted my answer but it doesn't seem to be upvoted because it was too late and people **tend** to upvote the top upvoted answer only, I don't care since I've solved my problem but the ***sad*** thing, a totally ***misleading*** top-upvoted answer about ***vector swizzling***...

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> I would like to ask what should I do now, or what should have happened
>   in first place. Should I have flagged the comment at the start asking
>   for an answer to the other question? Should I currently flag the
>   question for moderator attention, since it seems legit and there's no
>   other option as off-topic or unclear? Or should I just leave it as it
>   is and move on since I've done my part?

You're close. Flag the comment as no longer needed and leave your answer as is. The answers we give aren't just for the OP to solve their specific problem, but for all future visitors as well. That OP's question was asking something different then they actually wanted is OP's problem, not yours. But questions shouldn't be completly morphed so far as to invalidate answers.

In the end OP does actually need to open a new question then.