# Was this a valid answer?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534776/java-interface-derived-from-class/34534959#34534959) as not an answer. To me, it did not look like it answered the original question. The user was not wanting to use a different platform, so I am thinking it should have been a comment.

Was this a valid answer?

Comment: It attempts to answer the question. It may be misguided or flat-out wrong (perhaps misunderstanding the question), but it's still an answer. Downvote if you feel it deserves it, and move on.

Comment: @PaulRoub thanks. I actually flagged it as not an answer, I'll remember this as acceptable answers.

Comment: The bit about finding an error in the OP's code is useful info and I noticed that problem just looking at it. However, telling someone to let Eclipse do the work is not very helpful in my opinion.

Comment: Mandatory read on NAA flags: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275913/op-asked-about-problems-after-using-x-the-right-answer-is-use-y-instead-what

Comment: Downvote wrong answers, flag non-answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If an answer is wrong, but attempts to answer the question, *it is still an answer.*

The only time to use *Not an Answer* flags is right there in the description:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Don't use them if an answer is factually wrong, but rather when the content in the answer space does not belong there (it belongs somewhere else).

---

If you think that an answer is not correct, then use down votes, and not flags :)

Comment: Nice answer, but that makes me wonder: the 'answer' is not an actual answer but an alternative solution - as in "I don't know how to do it the way you're asking, but you can use this other tool right here". Arguably that falls in the NAA category, it should at best have been a comment, but probably just not be there at all as it is irrelevant to the question asked.